# Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have two servers but running generally the same setups - IIS, SQL Server, etc. One gives me this error, the other doesn't. I publish the same code from Visual Studio to both.

They are both running `.NET CLR Version v4.0.30319`, which I believe is `4.5`.

[Some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558827/method-not-found-system-string-system-string-formatsystem-iformatprovider-sy) say you have to target another version, If I change that in visual studio, everything breaks, so it is not that. Also, the same code runs on the others server.

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found) say that some old DLL's could be the reason. I didn't deploy to the working server, so maybe some newer DLLs were copied? But how could I know?

Also, the error doesn't seem to be in my code, rather in the framework and Umbraco, so I don't think I should be going in and updating string functions or something like that:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'.]
   System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.CheckMediaTypeFormat(String mediaType, String parameterName) +0
   System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue..ctor(String mediaType) +33
   System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants..cctor() +45

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants' threw an exception.]
   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor() +99
   System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters() +49
   System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes) +255
   System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<CreateConfiguration>b__0() +78
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +14308960
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +524
   Umbraco.Web.WebBootManager.InitializeResolvers() +1530
   Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.Initialize() +814
   Umbraco.Web.WebBootManager.Initialize() +19
   Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(Object sender, EventArgs e) +244

[HttpException (0x80004005): The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants' threw an exception.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +588
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +452

[HttpException (0x80004005): The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants' threw an exception.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +778
```

Generally, there isn't much info on Google, so not sure what could be done. Any insights are welcome!

Comment: Deleted the previous comment, just saw your clarification on @Risto M's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.6#System_String_Format_System_IFormatProvider_System_String_System_Object_), that overload seem to be available only on .NET 4.6. It is possible that servers has different .NET Framework versions.

Closest overload on .NET 4.5:

```
Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])
```

On .NET 4.6 there is exactly same overload:

```
Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object)
```

Ensure that both servers has .NET 4.6 installed properly.

Comment: Actually, none of them have 4.6. Here is the `working` server: https://imgur.com/XBJcB1F and here is the same server from regedit: https://imgur.com/a/1cFZOja

Comment: If you check latest .NET version from registry, what does it say as `Version`-attribute on registry value: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`   (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

Comment: My bad, I just realized I wasn't checking it correctly. When I dug more I saw there was this difference you mentioned: https://imgur.com/a/UFJgpSg `Thanks!`

Comment: Good to hear that!

Comment: @mgPePe so did one of them not have 4.6 installed? Just curious, this was an interesting question.

Comment: @pep Correct - it said 4.0 on both, but when digging down to `v4\Full` as @Risto M suggested, it turns out one had 4.5 and the other one 4.6 installed. I just didn't know how to check this correctly